# Bash Script + Read Line by Line + Ambiguos Redirect?

Tags: file, bash, while-loop

I have this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="file.txt"

while read line
do
    command $line > $line

done < $cmd
```

And this .txt file:

```
./cmd var1 var2 var3
./cmd var1 var2 var3
./cmd var1 var2 var3
./cmd var1 var2 var3
```

My goal is to read each line and execute the command, but I keep getting this error:

```
 line x: $line: ambiguos redirect
```

I am new to BASH and I have no idea what this error means and while researching it, dozens of various explanations came up. Does any1 have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It appears that you want to invoke the command "var1 var2 var3" and put the output in a file named "var1 var2 var3".  That seems very odd.

Comment: I think I wasnt able to exactly explain what I am trying to do. I want each line executing like this: ´./cmd var1 var2 var´ - I edited my example above and included the cmd to the script in the text lines.

Comment: `command` is a bash builtin.  If you want to demonstrate with a generic example, it would be better to use something else: `cmd` perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're executing is essentially:

```
command var1 var2 var3 > var1 var2 var3
```

The shell can't figure out which file you want the output to redirect to: `var1`, `var2`, or `var3`

I'm not certain what you're trying to do, but if you want to output to, say `var1`, then you could do:

```
while read firstVar line; do
  command $firstVar $line > $firstVar
done < file.txt
```

However, if--as your post says--you only want to *execute* the command, then you don't need redirection at all.  Simply do:

```
while read line; do
  command $line
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Actually, bash is quite happy to write to the file named "var1 var2 var3".  Something else is wrong here.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I've never tried that.  Removing post for now then.

Comment: No, actually, I just realized I was testing in zsh.

Comment: I think I wasnt able to exactly explain what I am trying to do. I want each line executing like this: ´./cmd var1 var2 var´ - I edited my example above and included the cmd to the script in the text lines.

Comment: This was it! :) Its my second try ever to write a simple script myself, therefor I am sorry that I initially wasnt able to explain what exactly I need.

Comment: One last thing if you dont mind: is it possible to remove each line after it has been executed?

Comment: @Andrej You should probably open up a new question for this so that it's preserved for posterity instead of buried in the comments.  But the easiest thing to do would be to `echo` the commands that *did* execute to a new file (`command $line && echo "$line" > executed.txt`), then run `sort file.txt executed.txt | uniq -u` to figure out which ones didn't execute.